# Is it possible to extend the built-in Event class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Code:

```
class MyEvent extends Event {
    constructor(name) {
        super(name);
    }
}

var event = new MyEvent("mousemove");
```

Runtime error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Event': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Event': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

The issue is with the `Event` *definition inside the v8 runtime*. it doesn't lend itself to `class` based extension. The same issue used to exist for error, i.e. the following used to fail:

```
class MyError extends Error {
    constructor(message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

const error = new MyError("some message");
```

So at the moment. You *cannot* extend the `Event` class in TypeScript (or ES6 classes).

Comment: Yup. [Engines aren't there yet](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5069#issuecomment-145139205).

Comment: Thanks for the link @DavidSherret

Answer (score 1):

You can create a static class which will be events provider:

```
static class EventProvider {

    static createEvent(name: string): Event {
        return new Event(name);
    }

    static createCustomEvent<T>(name: string, detail: T): CustomEvent<T> {
        return new CustomEvent<T>(name, { detail: detail });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Event` is not defined as a Class in Typescript since it's a JS object. What you want in this case is a wrapper class that calls `Event`'s methods the way you want. You can then extend that wrapper.

Comment: `Event is not defined as a Class in Typescript since it's a JS object` this is not the limitation the user is hitting. `Event` is defined with `new` signatures which allows inheritance in TypeScript (similar to `Error`). See my answer  